# This query/database is not working well together

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

Here's a query:

```
SELECT 
   *,
   COUNT(*) as `numauth` 
FROM `favorites` as `f1` 
INNER JOIN `story` as `s1` ON `f1`.`story_id` = `s1`.`story_id` 
WHERE `f1`.`story_id` != '".addslashes($_REQUEST['storyid'])."' 
   AND `f1`.`story_id` != '".addslashes($_REQUEST['storyid2'])."' 
   AND EXISTS (
               SELECT 1 FROM `favorites` as `f2` 
                WHERE `story_id` = '".addslashes($_REQUEST['storyid'])."' 
                AND `f2`.`auth_id` = `f1`.`auth_id`) 
                AND EXISTS (
                            SELECT 1 FROM `favorites` as `f3` 
                            WHERE `story_id` = '".addslashes($_REQUEST['storyid2'])."' 
                            AND `f3`.`auth_id` = `f1`.`auth_id`) 
                            AND NOT EXISTS (
                                            SELECT 1 FROM `favorites` as `f4` 
                                            WHERE `story_id` = 
                                            '".addslashes($_REQUEST['exclude'])."'                                                                                                  
                                            `f4`.`auth_id` = `f1`.`auth_id`) 
GROUP BY `f1`.`story_id` 
ORDER BY `numauth` DESC, `story_words` DESC
```

And here's a description of the tables...

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `favorites` (
  `fav_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `auth_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `story_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`fav_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `auth_id_2` (`auth_id`,`story_id`),
  KEY `auth_id` (`auth_id`),
  KEY `story_id` (`story_id`),
  KEY `fav_id` (`fav_id`,`auth_id`,`story_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1577985 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `story` (
  `story_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `story_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `story_desc` text NOT NULL,
  `story_authid` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `story_authname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `story_fandom` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `story_genre1` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `story_genre2` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `story_created` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `story_updated` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `story_reviews` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `story_chapters` smallint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `story_rating` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `story_words` mediumint(7) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `story_chars` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `story_id` (`story_id`),
  KEY `story_authid` (`story_authid`),
  KEY `story_fandom` (`story_fandom`),
  KEY `story_authid_2` (`story_authid`,`story_fandom`),
  KEY `story_id_2` (`story_id`,`story_authid`),
  KEY `story_id_3` (`story_id`,`story_words`),
  KEY `story_id_4` (`story_id`,`story_fandom`,`story_words`),
  KEY `story_id_5` (`story_id`,`story_reviews`,`story_words`),
  KEY `story_words` (`story_words`),
  KEY `story_reviews` (`story_reviews`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Now I've done a fair bit of optimizing to get the query down to this. I'm running on a dedicated server but the query is still taking 5-7 seconds, which is unacceptable. We're looking at about 800,000 records on favorites and 400,000 records on stories, and I'm lost at this point on where to look to next for improvements.

It seems a bit daunting, so even if someone can point me in the right direction I'll be happy.

EXPLAIN with sample inputs:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra 
1   PRIMARY s1  ALL story_id,story_id_2,story_id_3,story_id_4,story_id...   NULL    NULL    NULL    129429  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   PRIMARY f1  ref story_id    story_id    4   fanfic_jordanl_ffrecs.s1.story_id   2   Using where
4   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  f4  eq_ref  auth_id_2,auth_id,story_id  auth_id_2   8   fanfic_jordanl_ffrecs.f1.auth_id,const  1   Using index
3   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  f3  eq_ref  auth_id_2,auth_id,story_id  auth_id_2   8   fanfic_jordanl_ffrecs.f1.auth_id,const  1   Using index
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  f2  eq_ref  auth_id_2,auth_id,story_id  auth_id_2   8   fanfic_jordanl_ffrecs.f1.auth_id,const  1   Using index
```

Comment: One note, don't use `addslashes` on ints - just cast them to integers using `intval()` or `(int)`. Also, prefer `mysql_real_escape_string` to `addslashes`.

Comment: One small improvement would be to just do `count(fav_id)` rather than `count(*)`.

Comment: @Alex JL, prefer PDO over mysql_* functions.

Comment: can you please post the EXPLAIN output?

Comment: I've posted the explain output... I know that it's not using an index for the story table, but I'm not quite sure why.

Comment: @Jeremy no doubt, personally I've actually never used the mysql_* functions.

Comment: side note about your indexes, on the fav table you do not need a index on just auth_id, since it can use the UNIQUE INDEX for that

Comment: the story table as well has lots of duplicate indexes that can be combined. see http://tinyurl.com/37f7zmb and http://tinyurl.com/2buo9at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT  f1.*, s1.*, COUNT(*) as `numauth` 
FROM `favorites` as `f1` 
INNER JOIN `story` as `s1` ON `f1`.`story_id` = `s1`.`story_id` 
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT auth_id
        FROM favorites
        WHERE story_id IN ('".addslashes($_REQUEST['storyid'])."', '".addslashes($_REQUEST['storyid2'])."', '".addslashes($_REQUEST['exclude'])."')
        GROUP BY auth_id
        HAVING Count(IF(story_id = '".addslashes($_REQUEST['exclude'])."', 1, NULL)) = 0 AND Count(*) = 2 
        ) fv ON f1.auth_id = fv.auth_id
WHERE `f1`.`story_id` != '".addslashes($_REQUEST['storyid'])."' 
   AND `f1`.`story_id` != '".addslashes($_REQUEST['storyid2'])."' 
GROUP BY `f1`.`story_id` 
ORDER BY `numauth` DESC, `story_words` DESC
```

Since you are selecting * but not grouping by auth_id, what exactly are you trying to do?

--- UPDATE
since you do not need all the fav info for the stories, this query should perform better:

```
SELECT s.*, fv.cnt
FROM story s
    JOIN (
        SELECT fv.story_id, COUNT(*) cnt
        FROM favorites fv
            JOIN (
                SELECT auth_id
                FROM favorites
                WHERE story_id IN ('".addslashes($_REQUEST['storyid'])."', '".addslashes($_REQUEST['storyid2'])."', '".addslashes($_REQUEST['exclude'])."')
                GROUP BY auth_id
                HAVING Count(IF(story_id = '".addslashes($_REQUEST['exclude'])."', 1, NULL)) = 0 AND Count(*) = 2 
            ) ufv ON fv.auth_id = ufv.auth_id
        WHERE story_id != '".addslashes($_REQUEST['storyid'])."' AND story_id != '".addslashes($_REQUEST['storyid2'])."' 
        GROUP BY fv.story_id
        ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
        LIMIT 25
    ) fv ON s.story_id = fv.story_id
ORDER BY fv.cnt DESC, `story_words` DESC
```

Comment: The database is filled with stories and people who have favorited those stories. A user inputs a story they like and it finds all the users who have also favorites that story, then returns the stories with the highest number of common favorites among that group.

Comment: do you want to return all the common stories? or limit ~100? (the difference may be when the data is larger then sort_buffer_size)

Comment: and for the end-results, do you need just the common stories and a count of favorites? or you also need to know which of the users favorite the story

Comment: @user526171:  What is the purpose of the storyid2 and exclude elements in the request ?

Comment: I actually limit it to the top 25 results, but previous it was still sorting 100,000+ rows to get the 25 results.

Comment: storyid2 is a second seed story, meaning that we're only looking for users who have favorited both. Exclude removes all users who have that story in their favorites. And sam: I don't need to or want to know who favorited, only how many and then the relevent story info.

Comment: That final improvement brought the average query time from 12 seconds down to 3.5, going from 130,000 to 500 rows read. Great improvement there.

Comment: Now I just gotta figure out what to do about the advanced features... the advanced features do search and filter on the story table.

Comment: @user526171 can please post the EXPLAIN of the final query used?